# Python 3: How to change Anaconda default encoding library, and other encoding difficulties

Tags: python, encoding, anaconda

I'm pretty new to programming, and coming from Norway doesn't make it easier to make software for multiple users. I use Sublime text 3 as text editor.

I start the scripts with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
```

This should make it possible to use the Norwegian letters æøåÆØÅ, at least I think so. I can encode "Ø" to see the Unicode representation of the letter:

```
a = "Ø".encode("iso-8859-1")
print(a)
```

It yields:

```
b'\xc3\x98'
```

If i decode it back:

```
b = a.decode("iso-8859-1")
print(b)
```

It yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ojnyhus\Dropbox\programmering\myLibs\codec.py", line 68, in <module>
    print(b)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x98' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>
```

Shouldn't the library used be iso8859_1.py and not cp1252? In the former \x98 is defined. If I use the command line to run the script, cp850.py is used.

I have a hard time grasping how to easily and safely use the Norwegian characters with python. I want to collect strings from GUI inputs, and display and write them to files, but seeing as I can't control what the users input, I fear that the software will be horribly unstable.

Can anyone please point me in a direction that is not a mental hospital. I really feel the pain.